# efficient way of converting time string and inserting it to a time field django

Tags: python, django

For example, I have an input from a csv which is 08:00:00 so this is in string type.
and I have a timefield in the model. I need to insert that string in the timefield. Is there an efficient way of converting this and inserting it into a timefield? I know something but it's kinda like a long way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert it by using the `datetime`module of python

```
from datetime import datetime
t = '08:00:00'
t = datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M:%S')
print t, type(t)
>>> 1900-01-01 08:00:00 <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Note the year, month, day will start from `1900-01-01` because there is no date information available in the string.

Comment: i like this solution. :D i could easily insert t.time() :D

Answer (score 6):

TimeField will accept a datetime.time instance. Therefore, what you need is providing a time object for it

```
import datetime
a = YourModel()
a.YourTimeField = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:12:12', '%H:%M:%S').time()
a.save()
```

Comment: ya this is what I did after having amirs answer. though sorry aamir came first. so I just upvoted your answer. :) thanks!